# How to quantify the one-way flow of information in Markovian dynamics?

Tags: quantum-information, information, open-quantum-systems

It is said that in the Born-Markovian dynamics (Master equation), the information flow is one way, i.e. from the system to the environment. How to understand this sentence? Is there a quantity of the system that monotonically decreases over time in the Master equation? If there is, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a quantity which can be interpreted as the flow of information from the environment to the system, which should always be negative if your dynamics is Markovian.

Following [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0242.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.0238.pdf), given a CPTP map $\Phi$, two initial states $\rho_1(0)$ and $\rho_2(0)$ and their time evolutions, the trace distance $|\rho_1(t) - \rho_2(t)|$ is monotonically decreasing. This can be related to information flow as in the first reference.

One possible quantity you could take would be the case where $\rho_2(0) = \rho^*$, where $\rho^*$ is the steady state of your evolution.